# How to set an textbox / select as required - using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to know how I can set a textbox or an select to "required".

This is how it looks

```
<input type="textbox" name="SAP Pers. Nr." type="text" size="30" value="">
```

And after the js it should look like this

```
<input type="textbox" name="SAP Pers. Nr." type="text" size="30" value="" required>
```

May someone can help me?

Comment: There is no such thing as an `input type="textbox"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    document.getElementsByName('SAP Pers. Nr.').setAttribute('required','required');
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Comment: Does it work here ?   if(kategorie.value === 'Externer Mitarbeiter')
  {
  document.getElementById('extern').disabled = false;
  document.getElementsByName('extern').setAttribute('required','required');
}
  }

Comment: Should do. If all the elements exist (id extern and name extern).

Answer (score 1):

Add a onsubmit="return validateRequired() to your form, and in javascript you can do something like this:

```
function validateRequired()
{
    var textBox = document.getElementById('textBox');
    if (textBox.value == "")
        return false;
}
```

This will check if your textBox have a value, if no, it return false.
You need to add an id to your textBox for the getElementById to work.

Answer (score -2):

in html:-

```
<form name="frm">
  Question: <input name="question"/> <br />
  <input id="insert" onclick="return IsEmpty();" type="submit" value="Add Question"/>
</form>
```

javascript:-

```
function IsEmpty(){
  if(document.forms['frm'].question.value == "")
  {`enter code here`
    alert("empty");
    return false;
  }
```